# How to correct my OOP tendencies when programming in Haskell

Tags: oop, haskell, functional-programming

I have this recurrent problem when programming in Haskell. At some point, I try to simulate an OOP approach. Here I was writing some sort of AI for a flash game I found, and I'd like to describe the various pieces and the level as a list of pieces.

```
module Main where

type Dimension = (Int, Int)
type Position = (Int, Int)
data Orientation = OrienLeft | OrienRight

data Pipe = Vertical | Horizontal | UpLeft | UpRight | DownLeft | DownRight
data Tank = Tank Dimension Orientation
data Bowl = Bowl Dimension
data Cross = Cross
data Source = Source Dimension

-- desired
-- data Piece = Pipe | Tank | Bowl | Cross | Source

-- So that I can put them in a list, and define
-- data Level = [Piece]
```

I know I should abstract the functionalities and put Them in a list, but I often feel blocked in the process of writing code. What is the general mindset I should have in these situations?

Comment: I know exactly what you mean! Other than reading copious amounts of haskell examples, i sometimes wonder if standing on my head would help.

Comment: What is your problem with the code you posted? I don't see any error in it, and I don't see any OOP tendencies in it either. OOP is about behaviour, not data, and your snippet only contains data declarations.

Comment: I think the problem is that I would have to wrap every term in the Piece definition in another constructor, like in 
    data Piece = PPipe Pipe | PTank Tank | PBowl Bowl | PCross Cross | PSource Source.

Is this the best way I have?

Comment: FWIW, Haskell can do a better job of OOP than that with the help of a few extensions - start with [Ralf Lammels](http://channel9.msdn.com/tags/ralf-laemmel) series (the first two videos cover the expression problem), then look up higher-rank and existential polymorphism. That said, cases where these are genuinely needed seem fairly rare. As for mindset, the only cure is probably to resist the temptation until you get used to the new patterns and idioms. I've definitely got a long way to go yet too.

Comment: Why not simply `data Piece = VerticalPipe | HorizontalPipe | UpLeftPipe | UpRightPipe | DownLeftPipe | DownRightPipe | Tank Dimension Orientation | Bowl Dimension | Cross | Source Dimension`

Comment: Go ahead and continue your "OOP approch", remembering to "program to an interface" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface), then consider what that interface would be as a `data` in Haskell. Then you can decide whether you want the interface to be a `class` instead of `data`, or if you need to be able to recover every speck of the original pieces to be able to reason about them again later (in which case you need to have some `data` that keeps the original representation of any piece).

Answer (score 15):

You're on your way to some great code. Let me push it a few more steps toward a Haskell-like solution.

You've successfully modeled each `Piece` as an independent entity. This looks completely fine as is, but you want to be able to work with collections of pieces. The most immediate way to do this is to describe a type which can be any of the pieces desired.

```
data Piece = PipePiece   Pipe
           | TankPiece   Tank
           | BowlPiece   Bowl
           | CrossPiece  Cross
           | SourcePiece Source
```

which would let you write a list of pieces like

```
type Kit = [Piece]
```

but requires that when you consume your `Kit` that you pattern match on the different kinds of `Piece`s

```
instance Show Piece where
  show (PipePiece   Pipe)   = "Pipe"
  show (TankPiece   Tank)   = "Tank"
  show (BowlPiece   Bowl)   = "Bowl"
  show (CrossPiece  Cross)  = "Cross"
  show (SourcePiece Source) = "Source"

showKit :: Kit -> String 
showKit = concat . map show
```

There's also a strong argument for reducing the complexity of the `Piece` type by "flattening" out some redundant information

```
type Dimension   = (Int, Int)
type Position    = (Int, Int)
data Orientation = OrienLeft | OrienRight
data Direction   = Vertical | Horizontal | UpLeft | UpRight | DownLeft | DownRight

data Piece = Pipe Direction
           | Tank Dimension Orientation
           | Bowl Dimension
           | Cross
           | Source Dimension
```

which eliminates many redundant type constructors at the expense of no longer being able to reflect what kind of piece you have in the type of a function—no longer can we write

```
rotateBowl :: Bowl -> Bowl
rotateBowl (Bowl orientation) = Bowl (rotate orientation)
```

but instead

```
rotateBowl :: Piece -> Piece
rotateBowl (Bowl orientation) = Bowl (rotate orientation)
rotateBowl somethingElse      = somethingElse
```

which is pretty annoying.

Hopefully that highlights some of the tradeoffs between those two models. There's at least one  "more exotic" solution which uses type classes and `ExistentialQuantification` to "forget" about everything besides an interface. This is worth exploring as it's pretty tempting to do but is considered to be a Haskell anti-pattern. I'll describe it first then talk about the better solution.

To use `ExistentialQuantification` we remove the sum type `Piece` and create a type class for pieces.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

class Piece p where
  melt :: p -> ScrapMetal

instance Piece Pipe
instance Piece Bowl
instance ...

data SomePiece = forall p . Piece p => SomePiece p

instance Piece SomePiece where
  melt (SomePiece p) = melt p

forgetPiece :: Piece p => p -> SomePiece
forgetPiece = SomePiece

type Kit = [SomePiece]

meltKit :: Kit -> SomePiece
meltKit = combineScraps . map melt
```

This is an antipattern because `ExistentialQuantification` leads to more complex type errors and the erasure of lots of interesting information. The usual argument goes that if you're going to erase all information besides the ability to `melt` the `Piece`, you ought to have just melted it to begin with.

```
myScrapMetal :: [ScrapMetal]
myScrapMetal = [melt Cross, melt Source Vertical]
```

And if your typeclass has multiple functions then perhaps your real functionality is stored in that class. For instance, let's say we can `melt` a `piece` and also `sell` it, perhaps the better abstraction would be the following

```
data Piece = { melt :: ScrapMetal
             , sell :: Int
             }

pipe :: Direction -> Piece
pipe _ = Piece someScrap 2.50

myKit :: [Piece]
myKit = [pipe UpLeft, pipe UpRight]
```

In all honesty, this is almost exactly what you're getting via the `ExistentialQuantification` method, but much more directly. When you erase the type information via `forgetPiece` you leave only the typeclass dictionary for `class Piece`---this is exactly a product of the functions in the typeclass which is what we're explicitly modeling with the `data Piece` type just described.

---

The one reason I can think of to use `ExistentialQuantification` is best exemplified by Haskell's `Exception` system—if you're interested, take a look at how it's implemented. The short of it being that `Exception` had to be designed such that anyone could add a new `Exception` in any code and have it be routable through the *shared* `Control.Exception` machinery while maintaining enough identity for the user to catch it as well. This required the `Typeable` machinery as well... but it's almost certainly overkill.

---

The takeaway should be that the model you use will depend a lot on how you end up consuming your data type. Initial encodings where you represent everything as an abstract ADT like the `data Piece` solution are nice in that they throw away little information... but can also be both unwieldy and slow. Final encodings like the `melt`/`sell` dictionary are often more efficient, but require deeper knowledge about what a `Piece` "means" and how it will be used.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, there is no problem in the way you are thinking: it is fairly *abstract* and that is good.

As [suggested by Sassa NF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18868279/635669), you can use type classes and that would be very elegant. But in your example, I would expand it in a "simpler way", using *[abstract data type](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Abstract_data_type)*, since it seems the "natural way" that your thinking.

In this sense, your example would be something like, for example:

```
data Piece = Vertical 
           | Horizontal 
           | UpLeft 
           | UpRight 
           | DownLeft 
           | DownRight
           | Cross
           | Bowl Dimension
           | Source Dimension
           | Tank Dimension Orientation
```

And repeating it: I do not see problems in your way of modeling the problem since it seems abstract enough to me.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems 10 years ago, when I learned haskell.
Let me answer this in a more general way than your example above.

---

TL;DR:

Think in terms of OOP-like objects, that represent value-objects and function-objects, with heavy use of c++Templates/javaGenerics. Your program design should be based on data-flow through functions instead of references-to-mutable-memory that store intermediate object states. Those function-objects are composable at runtime.

---

Your statement *"At some point, I try to simulate an OOP approach."* describes your experienced way of designing programs.
As you might have heard somewhere, functional programming is considered harder to learn for OOP programmers than for newbies, because "wrong concepts" need to be unlearned first. That is not completely true, if you know how to use that to your advantage:

The trick is to use your OOP experience or more likely your imagination on "objects" in the opposite direction: How would you design haskell functions and haskell values with objects? How would you restructure your program to design a sane data flow using only these new concepts? In functional programming, every "value" is an object with only final/const properties -- or with a getter that allows lazy initialization (and with that it allows to implement seemingly infinite single linked lists). "Functions" are such "values", too. If you think about your programm using these concepts, you will easily master this without OOP design patterns but with "objects" that are actually functions and values.

If OOP is about managing memory cells that store mutable states/values, then functions are about calculating the next state/value from the previous. At some point you will see that you only think about combining functions for a sane dataflow and not about managing memory-locations-that-store-values.

The next step would be to see instances of type-classes as some kind of globally instanciated dictionary-objects that are automagically passed as invisible parameters to functions. The OOP classes of these dictionary-objects would use c++Templates/javaGenerics as type parameters, and their methods relate to their params and/or return value instead of any "this" reference. As soon as you understand when and how to use type-classes, they will become properties/roles/flavours of your types instead of imaginary objects.

IMHO, type-classes are one of the best/sanest OOP-design-patterns, but they are only known to very very few programmers and are not easily reinvented without functional thinking. (Every experienced haskell programmer that I know personally has reinvented type-classes as design-pattern in c++Templates/objC/js...)

The general way to learn to think in haskell or any other new strange language is to ask the question: "What can I do with this language easily and how?"
And not the question: "How can I write *this specific design* that actually fits to a completely different language that I'm already very experienced in?" (This sounds obvious, but we tend to forget that. Again and again.)

---

If your program really needs objects more in the OOP sense, then you might be looking for haskells records (if you are a beginner).
If those objects represent databases or similar *things*, you might be looking for lens libraries; but lenses might be (or might not be) very advanced/irritating for beginners.
Lenses are composable getterAndSetter "objects"(or values or function like things) that are used like "obj.lens1.lens2.modify()" in OOP -- which are in OOP stackable but neither composable nor objects themself.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking of polymorphism. There is place for that in Haskell, too, only it is done differently.

For example, it seems you want to process Pieces in a Level in a generic fashion. What is that processing? If you can define those functions, you will find that's like defining a Piece interface. In Haskell that will be a typeclass (defined as `class Piece a` with a list of functions the "implementations" should take care of).

Then you would need to define what those functions do for particular data types, for example `instance Piece Pipe` and add the definitions of those functions. Once you've done that for all data types, you can add them to the list of Pieces.

Comment: `Once you've done that for all data types, you can add them to the list of Pieces` - how would you do that? For example, we have `Show Char` and `Show Int`, but not `['a', 3 :: Int] :: ?`, so we need to build closed sum type `data CharInt = Char Char | Int Int` and then write `[Char 'a', Int 3] :: [CharInt]`, or use `GADTs`/`ExistentionalQuantification` for openness like `data ShowThing where { ShowThing :: Show a => a -> ShowThing }` with `[ShowThing 'a', ShowThing 3] :: [ShowThing]`.

Comment: @JJJ yes, in which case the question is back to the topic starter - it may really be easier to create a list of functions or a list of tuples of functions.